# Inconsistency between runs on Visual Studio, on a C project

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio, race-condition, consistency

I work on a multi-threaded C project, on Visual-Studio 2010.
When running the project twice, with the same input, the output **in some of the cases** may be different from run to run.
How can I debug this phenomenon? Is there any tool in Visual-Studio, or an add-on, to debug it?

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with your implementation of the threads. Sounds like there are race conditions. We can not tell you more without an [mcve]

Comment: Are you asking if Visual Studio comes with a debugger? Yes, it does... However, for spotting race condition bugs, manual code review by a programmer is the best tool. Post a minimal example on SO which contains the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found the cause of the problem. It's a static global that has caused the problem. Two threads use this variable, and so a race condition was indeed the problem. Thank you, Kami Kaze!

Comment: Classic! I remember doing that too. Just watched it in the debugger and wondered why the variables were just randomly changing!!

Comment: Just let me correct you: The changes are not entirely random. At least in my case, the data is not uniformly scattered across the entire dynamic range; it stays similar to the correct data, but not quite. Moreover, in case of an array, in many cases the first part of the data is identical, but the second isn't.